# Unable to find a substitute command for Bash's complete in Zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, tab-completion, git-completion

I put the newest git-completion.bash to my .zshrc and I get

```
/Users/Masi/bin/shells/git/git-completion.bash:2116: command not found: complete
/Users/Masi/bin/shells/git/git-completion.bash:2118: command not found: complete
```

The lines are

```
 complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _git git 2>/dev/null \
     || complete -o default -o nospace -F _git git 
 complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _gitk gitk 2>/dev/null \
     || complete -o default -o nospace -F _gitk gitk
```

**Which command is a substitute for Bash's complete in Zsh?**

Comment: Please close as "No longer relevant".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git's completion script has been updated to work with ZSH too. The latest version should "just work".

Answer (score 4):

I do believe it's a problem, since `complete` is a [built-in Bash command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins). It's part of Bash's programmable completion feature.

Comment: How to bind that `complete` to zsh?

Answer (score 2):

Bash and Zsh have different completion systems. Using bash completion functions with zsh might be possible, but only though a compatibility layer. I suggest you read `man zshcompsys`.