# command not found: complete

Tags: bash, autocomplete, terminal, zsh, homebrew

I have a fresh mac in front of me, I installed homebrew (just fine), and oh my zsh (just fine).

I'm trying to install autojump which is a intelligent database of directories. For example, you can 'jump' to `~/Documents` with `j doc` in terminal.

I did this

`brew install autojump`

I already have my .zshrc that looks fine I think. I added the line into it that it said:

```
[[ -s `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh ]] && . `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh
```

When I start iterm2 I get the following warning:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/autojump/21.3.0/etc/autojump.bash:13: command not found: complete
/usr/local/Cellar/autojump/21.3.0/etc/autojump.bash:55: = not found
```

I have used brew to install other things, and I can run `autojump -s` successfully so I know it is seeing the `$path`. I don't know what else could be wrong though, as this is all a fresh install.

Answer (score 9):

In your .zshrc, you must source **autojump.zsh**, not **autojump.bash**
(I do not know where it will be located on a Mac, but it will be in same folder as autojump.bash).

On Ubuntu, here is what you need to append at the end of your .zshrc:

```
source /usr/share/autojump/autojump.zsh
```

Answer (score 5):

To fix the problem, you should update the line:

```
[[ -s `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh ]] && . `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh
```

to say:

```
[[ -s `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.zsh ]] && . `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.zsh
```

i.e. use the **.zsh** version of the autojump script. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

[**That file**](http://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/blob/master/bin/autojump.bash) has no Shebang. This means that it is probably getting interpreted by Zsh.

This is a problem because `complete` is a [**Bash builtin**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/921219).

Perhaps [**this**](http://github.com/joelthelion/autojump#additional-configuration) can be a fix for you, or maybe

```
[[ -s `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh ]] && bash `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh
```

Comment: So I just add it manually? I just looked at another machine I have this running on and I don't have a shebang. My .bashrc, .bash_profile, .zshrc all match. So weird..

Answer (score 1):

In my case, comment out

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solve this issue adding :

```
autoload bashcompinit && bashcompinit
```

Before the first `complete` command.

I've used this link : [Fixed! az.completion:10: command not found: complete](https://jessicadeen.com/fixed-az-completion10-command-not-found-complete/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are mac user using **.zsh**

just add the following to your **.zsrc** file

```
autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
```

for more info refer to link : https://github.com/eddiezane/lunchy/issues/57

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```sh
[[ -s `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh ]] && . `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh
```

to your `~/.bash_profile`. Homebrew tells you this when you install but I didn't notice it the first time and came to this webpage as a result.